# Socket.io and React-native seTimeout warning

Tags: android, react-native, socket.io

I followed this link to set up socket.io with react: https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34

Installed packages

- socket.io-client: 2.0.4
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.48.3

Now I get the following warning when launching the app on the Android Emulator:
[image: Emulator]

I've tried using the following code:

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
const options = {
  pingTimeout: 3000,
  transports: ['websocket'],
  allowUpgrades: false,
  cookie: false
};
const socket = openSocket(url, options);
```

Comment: Have you tried this? : https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3054

Comment: Yes, see the code above

Comment: But you did it on the client. I came into the same issue, I added { pingTimeout: 30000 } to where I tie socket.io to the server, it worked. Try adding it to server side.

Comment: Oh you're right, let try it and I will get back to you! Thanks

Comment: It worked, thanks, you can add the answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add { pingTimeout: 30000 } to where you tie socket.io to the server.

```
var io = socketio(server, {pingTimeout: 30000})
```